# Why does Laravel's trans_choice() always show the singular case?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use `trans_choice()` to simply format a string to either "comment" or "comments" depending on the number of them. It should be fairly straightforward, like this.

In my view:

```
{{ trans_choice('posts.num comments', $post->comments->count()) }}
```

In the posts localisation file:

```
return [
    'num comments' => 'comment|comments',
];
```

However, every single one returns just "comment". And if I go into tinker:

```
>>> trans_choice('posts.num comments', 1);
=> "comment"
>>> trans_choice('posts.num comments', 2);
=> "comment"
>>> trans_choice('posts.num comments', 4);
=> "comment"
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but it looks to me as if I've followed the documentation perfectly.

Edit: The problem seems to lie somewhere in `Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector`, but I haven't yet figured the cause out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Apparently, if the locale isn't available in Symfony's PluralizationRules class, the translator defaults to the first pick - that is, always index zero. By changing the locale name (I didn't even realise it was misspelled...), I got it working.

Comment: Will mark this as accepted once I'm able to. I figure it may happen to somebody else in the future, so I don't want to just delete it.

Comment: Additionally: if you are using `APP_LOCALE` as `pt-br` or `pt-BR`, replace it with `pt_BR`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old, but I ran into this issue, so hoping my solution helps someone if [Joel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1520841/joel-hinz) solution doesn't work.

I'm working with Laravel 7.x, and am using localization on a project for differences between US an CA English, (i.e. Center vs. Centre).

I have my localization folders set up with **en** being the default folder and **en_ca** as the Canadian English folder, where **en** is also the fallback language.

When using `trans_choice()` I found I had to specifically set the the counts in my translation strings, otherwise the translation engine would just spit back the singular when viewing pages in the non-default locale.

Once the changes were made, `trans_choice()` worked, no matter what locale was set.

For example, wherever I had:

```php
'general.posts' => 'Posts|Posts',
```

I changed it to:

```php
'general.posts' => '{1} Post|[2,*] Posts',
```

After that everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you're brazilian that's probably your answer!

I just had the same problem and found out it was because of my locale option (and lang folder).
Instead of 'br' we must use 'xbr' in order to Symphony find it in PluralizationRules (vendor/symphony/translation/PluralizationRules).

In that file there's an array with all languages available, so may check it out.

P.S. I'm using Laravel 5.3